# What's the difference between the methods findAttribute() and getAttribute() in servlet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jstl

If I've set  "cart" as a session attribute, then what's the difference between the methods `pageContext.findAttribute("cart")` and `session.getAttribute("cart")` in servlet file ?
Do they do the same thing in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Was it really too much effort to read the Javadoc for [PageContext.findAttribute()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)?

The `PageContext` looks in multiple scopes for the attribute (page, request, session then application) whereas the `session.getAttribute()` only looks in the session. If you know the attribute is in the session, then `session.getAttribute()` should be (marginally) faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Object findAttribute (String AttributeName)**: This method searches for the specified attribute in all four levels in the following order – Page, Request, Session and Application. It returns NULL when no attribute found at any of the level.

**session.getAttribute("cart"):** This method searches for the specified attribute in only Session scope.

**Do they do the same thing in this case?**
=> They do same thing in this case if you dont have attribute name cart in Page, Request.